# Excel - Looping issue

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet that looks like this:

```
 --------------------------------------------------
 | cat | cat | cat | dog | bird | dog | dog | dog |
 --------------------------------------------------
 |     |     |     |     |      |     |     |     |
 --------------------------------------------------
```

I've created the below that reads the row above and skips if a value exists or enters data if it doesn't exist. This works well EXCEPT for when there's two or more of the values to skip in the row above.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim t As Integer
c = 5
t = 7
Dim animal As String
      For i = 1 To t
      ' this can be cat, dog or bird - from another sheet, this part works OK
      animal = Cells(3, c).Value 
      ' this is the part that doesn't work, it should move to next cell if one of those values exists
      If InStr(1, animal , "cat") Or InStr(1, animal , "bird") Or Instr(1, animal, "duck") Then
            c = c + 1
      End If

      Cells(4, c).Value = "yes"
      c = c + 1
Next i
```

I've tried a combination of different things which all seem to have varying results but this is as close as I've been able to get it :(

It's meant to do this:

```
 --------------------------------------------------
 | cat | cat | cat | dog | bird | dog | dog | dog |
 --------------------------------------------------
 |     |     |     | yes |      | yes | yes | yes |
 --------------------------------------------------
```

But instead it's doing this - I believe because it's saying, yes cat means, next col so I'll add a yes (not checking the col it's in again):

```
 --------------------------------------------------
 | cat | cat | cat | dog | bird | dog | dog | dog |
 --------------------------------------------------
 |     | yes |     | yes |      | yes | yes | yes |
 --------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I don't understand - do you want it to say yes just for 'dog'?

Comment: @Vlad Kind of, it's been modified to remove a lot of information so understand it would be harder to interpret - basically the top row might have dog 1234, dog 281, dog 2899, cat 02928, duck 9228 in it, hence the searching for cat, bird, duck. If any of those appear in the top row, I want it to move to the next cell and paste it in but it's not checking the above row for the next cell as it pastes - does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add all strings to be compared in an array and then check existence of cell value in an array and accordingly perform further actions.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim lastColumn As Long, i As Long
    Dim animal As String
    Dim arr()

    arr = Array("cat", "bird", "duck")  'store all strings in array to match
    lastColumn = Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column   'get last column with data in Row 3

    For i = 5 To lastColumn     'loop through Row 3 starting from Column 5
        animal = Cells(3, i).Value
        If IsError(Application.Match(animal, arr, False)) Then  'check if animal is in array
            Cells(4, i).Value = "yes"                           'enter animal in Row 4
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

***EDIT 1 :*** As per comment

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim lastColumn As Long, i As Long
    Dim animal As String

    lastColumn = Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column   'get last column with data in Row 3

    For i = 5 To lastColumn             'loop through Row 3 starting from Column 5
        animal = Cells(3, i).Value
        If InStr(1, animal, "cat") = 0 And InStr(1, animal, "bird") = 0 And InStr(1, animal, "duck") = 0 Then
            Cells(4, i).Value = "yes"   'enter animal in Row 4
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

***EDIT 2 :***

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim lastColumn As Long, i As Long, t As Long
    Dim animal As String

    lastColumn = Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column   'get last column with data in Row 3

    t = 9
    i = 5   'this should be the column number from where data starts
    Do While t > 0
        animal = Cells(3, i).Value
        If InStr(1, animal, "cat") = 0 And InStr(1, animal, "bird") = 0 And InStr(1, animal, "duck") = 0 Then
            Cells(4, i).Value = "yes"
            t = t - 1
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: @hylian - See edit in answer. Code updated as per your comment in the question.

Comment: Updated one fixes the initial problem, however the for loop in the OP is meant to loop a varying number of times, in your solution it loops until the end of the row. So sometimes it might loop 4 times, others 7, depending on another var in the sheet.

Comment: @hylian - Where exactly is that value?

Comment: in my OP I've defined it as 't = 7' - sorry for confusion. In the real world scenario it's defined by getting the value of another cell. Note that it works fine and loops the correct amount of times.

Comment: @hylian - Then you can write `lastColumn = Range("A1").Value` replace `A1` to your actual cell.

Comment: T value getting from another cell? can you please say that cell?

Comment: @Mrig - it needs to loop the amount of times in the cell, in this example its 7 times not including skipped loops. So it needs to add that yes value 7 times into cells,  not counting no values.  But because i starts on 5 it will only loop twice. Does that make sense? That's why I had it the original way.

Comment: @hylian - If I understood this correctly, even if the data in `Row 3` is not present then also loop should continue till, `yes` value in entered in `Row 4` 7 times.

Comment: @hylian - If my above comment is correct then see `EDIT 2` in answer.

Comment: @Mrig - that's it! I had thought about using While but thought For would work.

Answer (score 1):

your program is doing exactly what you told it to do

```
your code flow:

point to first column (1)
is it cat/bird/duck? yes (cat) ... point to next column (2)
put in "yes"
point to next column (3)

is it cat/bird/duck? yes (cat) ... point to next column (4)
put in "yes"
point to next column (5)

is it cat/bird/duck? yes (bird)... point to next column (6)
put in "yes"
point to next column (7)

is it cat/bird/duck? no
put in "yes"
point to next column (8)

is it cat/bird/duck? no
put in "yes"
point to next column (9)
```

Comment: Understand, without having multiple nested If statements how do I get it to do what I want it to do?